# Backbone Script Files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

as i am building an application in backbone, i have come up with a major doubt if i can use third party jquery script file(here: bootstrap) in my backbone application or is it not a good practice ??

I also would like to get my script file order rechecked, as my files are not running when i am placing these script files within my head tag??

```
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/libs/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/libs/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/libs/curl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/libs/lodash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/routers/router.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/models/drug-model.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/views/drug-views.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/data.json" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, you can use Backbone with third party libraries.

Comment: Why are you loading two different versions of `jQuery` and both `underscore` and `lodash`?

Comment: @J.Titus figured out why i was going wrong as underscore.js and lodash.js are known for similar functionalities. thnx for pointing that out. works fine now!!